# How to do an automatic join using SQLAlchemy core?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have the below ORM schema in sqlalchemy that represents my DB, and I want an automatic join with invoices from customer.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String

Base = declarative_base()


class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    address = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    invoices = relationship("Invoice", primaryjoin="Customer.id == Invoice.custid")


class Invoice(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'invoices'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    custid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("customers.id"))
    invno = Column(Integer)
    amount = Column(Integer)
```

If I use this statement:

`s = session.query(Customer, Invoice).join(Customer.invoices)`

It gives me the correct result:

```
SELECT customers.id AS customers_id, customers.name AS customers_name, customers.address AS customers_address, customers.email AS customers_email, invoices.id AS invoices_id, invoices.custid AS invoices_custid, invoices.invno AS invoices_invno, invoices.amount AS invoices_amount FROM customers JOIN invoices ON customers.id = invoices.custid
```

But I want to use the core of SQL Alchemy using Select, Join, without query, how could I do it?

I tried with:

```
j = Customer.join(Customer.invoices)
stmt = select([Customer,Invoice]).select_from(j)
```

but is not working, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The result is:

```
s = select([Customer, Invoice]).select_from(join(Customer, Invoice))
```